# Can't fetch json file with axios in Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, axios

I have a very large json file that I want to fetch from and I did try this code but no data is being returned...

```
axios.get('/storage/db.json') .then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
})
```

The only thing I get back is this:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the object with a given "DOT_NUMBER"?

[image]

Comment: Whe you open the uri `storage/db.json` by browser do you have the page with `JSON` data or the `JSON` data was be dowloaded on your computer like single file?

Comment: yes I do get the entire json file in the browser when I go to ```/storage/db.json```. But  I don't want to load 1 million records... I want to just fetchone record based on the ```dot_number``` property